# Maven 3 cobertura 2.5.1 configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tdd, maven-3, cobertura

I have configured cobertura in a maven 3 project. My requirement is to configure cobertura in parent pom and configure the ignore, exclude values in child poms in multiple projects. The basic configuration of cobutura plugin in pom xml with reference to it in child pom worked fine. But when i tried to configure ignore, exclude packages in child pom and added instrument goal in parent pom, i'm getting directory issues with the plugin. Google search gave me this link, but not successful so far. : http://blog.bielu.com/2012/01/errata-to-maven2-maven3-migration.html

Here is my configuration:

Parent pom:

```
 <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <check>
                    <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                    <branchRate>50</branchRate>
                    <lineRate>50</lineRate>
                    <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                    <totalBranchRate>50</totalBranchRate>
                    <totalLineRate>50</totalLineRate>
                    <packageLineRate>50</packageLineRate>
                    <packageBranchRate>50</packageBranchRate>
                </check>
            </configuration>
            <executions>  
                <execution>
                    <id>instrument-code</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>  
                    <id>verify</id>  
                    <phase>verify</phase>  
                    <goals>                             
                      <goal>check</goal>  
                    </goals>  
                </execution> 
            </executions>             
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
```

Child pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <instrumentation>
                <ignores>
                  <ignore>to.ignore.*</ignore>
                </ignores>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>to/exclude/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </instrumentation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

Error thrown:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:instrument (instrument-code) on project test: Unable to prepare instrumentation directory. source and destination are the same directory.
```

Tried several configuration, but no luck yet. Please advice me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: That i don't understand why are you defining a configuration in the build section whereas cobertura is mostly a reporting plugin.

Comment: i need to configure cobertura to check the coverage rates and fail the build. Also i saw the similar thing here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Shouldn't that made by a CI solution and not during ervery build.

Comment: Yeah, but this issue is not related to it. Even thought i configure CI with these settings, the same issue gonna popup... i would like to know whether my plugin settings are correct and why this instrument issue occurs... or any better ways to configure ignore/exclude settings in child projects... thanks.